# Python remove empty and null keys doesn't effect my object

Tags: python, json, null

I'm trying to remove null and empty keys from my python object by calling a method from a module.

```
from file2 import remove_nulls
# initialize object and set attributes
obj.remove_nulls()
```

In my `remove_nulls()` method, if I print the resultant object, I can observe that null and empty keys are removed, but after returning from the function, the final object still has the null and empty keys.

```
def remove_null(feature):
    return json.dumps(del_none(feature.__dict__.copy()))

def del_none(d):
  for key, value in list(d.items()):
    if value is None:
        del d[key]
    elif isinstance(value, dict):
        del_none(value)
  return d
```

Can someone help to fine where it went wrong?

Comment: Your `return` is inside the `for` loop. It should be after it.

Comment: also you need to `return del_none(value)` classic dupe

Comment: .. and neither of the functions you've included are the ones being called, since you call a method on the object `obj`, and neither the `remove_null(feature)` function or the `del_none(d)` function matches the signature (.. or is part of a class)

Comment: @MatsLindh, i've not put my exact code, it's just an example to explain the flow, the method is called in my code,  if i print the object before return statement, i can see that the null values are removed, but after calling the method in my file, if i print the object i can see that the nulls still exists.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, its not duplicate, please read again.

Answer (score 1):

Just too many copies...:

```
def remove_null(feature):
    return json.dumps(del_none(feature.__dict__.copy()))
```

that applies `del_none` on a copy of your object, dumps the proper "cleaned" object, then returns, leaving your object untouched (since you created a copy). You probably need to do just:

```
def remove_null(feature):
    return json.dumps(del_none(feature.__dict__))
```

The confusion probably comes from the need to copy the dictionary keys+values  to avoid removing items on a dict while iterating on it (which was probably handled here, at the wrong level, then handled at the proper level, but the first copy was not removed)